# How to use mux router path in golang?

Tags: go

Using `github.com/gorilla/mux` I do this:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/qa/{cat}",qaall)
        router.HandleFunc("/qadetail/{id}",GetQuestionAnswerDetail)
```

Above file is working because we pass the `{}` but when we pass this on

```
router.HandleFunc("/AddQuestion",AddQuestion)
```

It gives me the following error:

> http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:57748: ObjectIDs must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 0)

Comment: Please show the request URL that results in the error. You should convert MongoDB ids to and from hex when encoding them in URLs.

Comment: localhost:9090/AddQuestion

Comment: OK, now show the code for AddQuestion.